# Convert JS value to PHP array or object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, laravel

`js code output : "feesCode":"[26,501,502]"`

Following JS output is string data type. But to perform further works. I need to convert this into PHP array or object.

```
js : 

var $inputs = $('#collection-form :input');
    var values = {};
    $inputs.each(function() {
        values[this.name] = $(this).val();
    });

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
        },
        type: "POST",
        url:  "/make-collection",
        data: {data : values}
    });
```

```
Controller.php


public function createCollection(Request $request)
    {
        $inputs = $request->all();
        if(is_array($inputs['data']['code'])){
            echo 'True';
        }else{
            echo 'False';
        }
}
```

**Output : False. ***

How can I get the output as array in PHP ?

Answer (score 0):

I purpose it happens in cause input value is string. You need to walk through input value and make an array from it. Tryout this

```
const array = this.val().split(',').reduce((acc, rec) =>, [...acc, rec] [])
value[this.name] = array;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
 public function createCollection(Request $request)
  {
  if(is_array($_POST['data'])){
    echo 'True';
   }else{
    echo 'False';
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) to solve my issue.